# DC drain voltage of serie connection of pMos and nMos

Tags: mosfet

In the very simple following circuit made out of a pMos in series with a nMos:

[image]

I do not understand how to compute the Vout DC voltage when **neglecting channel-length modulation** and assuming **both transistors are in saturation**. Indeed, it seems to me that the only tool I can use to compute that voltage is the ID current that is common to both transistors. However, since they are in saturation, the current does only depend on VGS of both transistors.

I thank you in advance for your help.